# Отметить чекбокс если определенные данные присутствуют в строке таблицы

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть страница с таблицами. Нужно взять строку из таблицы, в которой есть несколько полей(Имя, дата, чекбокс ...) если имя совпадает с заданым, нужно нажать чекбокс.. Как правильно реализовать? C# Selenium
* Кусок кода на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Дубликат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/951970/179763) [Мультиакк?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/329007/user329007)

Comment: @tym32167 Если честно, странно, что в заполненном акке, на день позже появляется вопрос который задавался новым акком ранее. Я даже не знаю, какой из них отметить дубликатом, тот что был раньше на пустом профиле, или тот что позже но на заполненном?

Comment: @AtachiShadow вы дублем вопрос отмечаете, а не автора, потому дубликат тот, который был позже создан.

Comment: @tym32167 так то вы правы... но там нужен ответ), что-бы посчитать его дубликатом

Comment: @AtachiShadow ну лично мое мнение - это необязательно. Но в конкретном этом случая я уже проголосовал за закрытие вопроса по другой причине.

Comment: @tym32167 как я понимаю, за мультиакк?

Comment: @AtachiShadow поставил за `непонятна суть вопроса`, потому уже вспомнил, что такой вопрос уже был, но менять ничего не стал

Comment: @tym32167 а я выбрал "требуется модератор" написал что вопрос дубликат с мультиакка

Comment: @AtachiShadow модера я тоже позвал, но это делается не в закрытии вопроса, а в тревогах

Comment: @tym32167 да, в тревоге и сделал)